# treeview with select option, to add selected in odoo

Tags: treeview, odoo-9

I need to create a popup treeview like the one in picture below, and then can select as many items as I need to be inserted to the original tree-view

[image]

Comment: Then create what is the problem? Describe your question

Comment: how to do so?, I created tree view as normal but when I click on add new item in original tree view it gave me create popup not the one in the pic

Comment: You need to create custom view, create button is calling model create function so it;s logical when it doesn't open.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to give you a popup containing a tree view where you can choose from the list. You need to have a many2many relation between the 2 modules, it seems like you have one2many relation.

Comment: aha, so it must be many2many to get the result I need?, but what if I need the same result when the relation is one2many?

Comment: If you have a one2many relation, you will always need to create a new element. because the other elements already existing are already related to another element. that's the one2many relation. It's like the relation between a class and the students attending this class.

Comment: I made the relation many2many and changed the form view code to be 

<field name="partner_id" widget="many2many">
   <tree>
      <field name="name"/>
      <field name="city"/>
      <field name="state"/>
   </tree>
</field>
thanks tessnim, please to modify your answer so I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0):

if your field is a one2many field  from what i understand your field must be a one2many field because in one2many field when you click on add item it send you direclty to a create popup in order to change this behavor you need to change the widget of this field like this :

```
<field name="you_o2m_field_name" widget="many2many" >
  <tree>
     <field name="field_name1"/>
     <field name="field_name1"/>
     <field name="field_name1"/>
  </tree>
<form>
  <!-- you can put a costum form view also  here -->
</form>
</field>
```

but you i think you need to give it an option not_delete like this

```
<field name="you_o2m_field_name" widget="many2many" options="{'not_delete':True}"/>
```

because when you remove the record from the tree one2many delete it from the table if you want to keep it then use no_delete option

define a search view for the model exam

```
<record id="id_for_this_view_here" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">model.name</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="recherche" >
                    <field name="field_name" />
                    <field name="field_name"/>
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>
```

the frame work will create a search view for you if you don't specify one for your model this why the search have only create by ok so whenever you have a search view with create by you need to define a _rec_name for your model or create a search view

Comment: when using your code with one2many relation I got tree view with only " Created by " field which has users listed only

Comment: you can put your costum tree

Comment: i edit my answer inside the field one2many or many2many you can put a tree view or a form view or the both than the frame work will not call the default tree he will call the costum view

Comment: ahhh ok you need to create a search for your model the framework is calling the default search view wich is the create by  because your model don't have any _rec_name  the default search view have only create by just create a search view for your model than the frame work will call it

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, but to make it work fine I have to change the relation to be many2many while it is not the case in my project

Comment: i don't know but it work fine in odoo 9 for me if you want help edit your question and put the code of the two model and the form view code than i will help you